# Connecting to remote hive metastore from a Spark program in Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

First let's create a `hive-enabled` spark session:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
```

Then let's try to connect to the remote dB:

```
spark.sql("use my_remote_db").show

17/12/10 10:27:02 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database my_remote_db, returning NoSuchObjectException
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'my_remote_db' not found;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.setCurrentDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.SetDatabaseCommand.run(databases.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
    at com.mycompany.sbseg.graph.poc.features.LoadGraphData$.loadGraphData(LoadGraphData.scala:8)
```

Note: this same code ***works in the spark-shell***.

Here are the additional settings made in `Intellij` to emulate the `bash` shell environment used to run `spark-shell`:

[image]

To ensure they were getting set properly they are printed out:

```
Seq("SPARK_HOME","HIVE_CONF_DIR","HIVE_HOME")
 .foreach{ s=>println(s"$s:${System.getenv(s)}")}
```

These print out the same/correct results as on the command line.

```
/shared/spark
/Users/sboesch/yarnconf
/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.1/libexec
```

So it is unclear what the differences might be between the Intellij and the bash environments  - and why the code does not work properly in the former.